# Ajax .post() method doesn't send data to the server

Tags: php, ajax, .post

I've got 2 web-pages named *test1.html* and *test1.php*. I'm sending some data as key/value pairs using ajax .post() method, but it doesn't seem to reach the server side as I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: Undefined variable $name in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebMid2Practice\ajax\test1.php on line 6
>
> Warning: Undefined variable $age in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebMid2Practice\ajax\test1.php on line 7

Here's my code:

*test1.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ajax</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#load").click(function() {
                    var txtName = $("#name").val();
                    var txtAge = $("#age").val();
                    $.post("test1.php", {name:txtName, age:txtAge}, function(data) {
                        $("#result").html(data);
                    });
                })
                
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Ajax Practice</h1>
        <div class="result"></div>
        Enter Name: <input type="text" id="name"><br>
        Enter age: <input type="text" id="age"><br>
        <button id="load">Send request to test1.php</button>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

*test1.php*

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['name']) && isset($_REQUEST['age'])) {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $age = $_REQUEST['age'];
    }
    echo "Name entered is: " .$name;
    echo "Age: " .$age;
?>
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: _"jquery/1.11.2"_... holy ancient jQuery versions, Batman! Time to update

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Does the Network tab show that it's sending the parameters?

Comment: What is the context for the errors? Are those warnings what you see added to your `#result` div after the request completes or are you seeing them somewhere else? If so, where?

Comment: @Barmar yes it shows status 200 OK.

Comment: @Phil no, the #result div is empty. I'm seeing the warnings on test1.php.

Comment: The point of my question was whether you see the parameters in the Payload tab of the AJAX call.

Comment: The browser shouldn't be opening test1.php, since you're using AJAX. How are you seeing test1.php.